# Listview populates, but the adapter claims to be empty

Tags: android, listview, android-contentprovider, simplecursoradapter, android-listfragment

So I'm developing an app over the summer. It stores items in the database, displays them in a listview (otherwise makes Toast telling the user its empty), and allows users to see details by clicking on one. Eventually I plan on having search criteria narrow down the list, but I'm not there yet.

My problem is that the listview seems to be populating, but the app makes Toast....

ResultsActivity.java

```
public class ResultsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ResultsFragment.OnPlantSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_results);
    }// method: FragmentActivity.onCreate() 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.results, menu);
        return true;
    }// method: FragmentActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu()

    /* Custom methods */

    //@Override
    public void onPlantSelected(long id){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlantViewActivity.class);
        //TODO confirm id
        intent.putExtra(DBContentProvider.KEY_PLANT_ID, id);
        startActivity(intent);      
    }// method: ResultsFragment.OnPlantSelectedListener.onPlantSelected(long)
}// class: ResultsActivity extends ListActivity
```

ResultsFragment.java

```
public class ResultsFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
    private static OnPlantSelectedListener emptyPlantSelectedListener = new OnPlantSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPlantSelected(long id){}
    };
    private static OnPlantSelectedListener plantSelectedListener = emptyPlantSelectedListener;

    private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";
    private int activatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    public ResultsFragment(){}

    /* Fragment Lifespan */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] dbPlantColumns = {DBContentProvider.KEY_GENUS_TEXT, DBContentProvider.KEY_SPECIES, 
                DBContentProvider.KEY_COMMON_NAME_GROUP};
        int[] fragPlantFields = {R.id.result_item_txt_genus, R.id.result_item_txt_species, 
                R.id.result_item_txt_common_name};
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0x01, null, this);//null can be replaced by a Bundle of search criteria
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item_results, 
                null, dbPlantColumns, fragPlantFields, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        if(adapter.isEmpty())//This returns true
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Nothing returned from the database", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }// method: Activity.onCreate(Bundle)

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)){
            setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
        }
    }// method: ListFragment.onViewCreated(View, Bundle)

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (!(activity instanceof OnPlantSelectedListener)){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement fragment's listener.");
        }
        plantSelectedListener = (OnPlantSelectedListener) activity;
    }// method: ListFragment.onAttach(Activity)

    @Override
    public void onDetach(){
        super.onDetach();
        plantSelectedListener = emptyPlantSelectedListener;
    }// method: ListFragment.onDetach()

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (activatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION){
            outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, activatedPosition);
        }
    }// method: ListFragment.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)

    /* LoaderManager abstract methods */    
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args){
        //TODO parse args for searching. Second null is String[]; index 0-17 are search arguments.
        String[] arguments = new String[18];
        String[] dbPlantColumns = {DBContentProvider.TABLE_PLANT + "." + DBContentProvider.KEY_PLANT_ID, 
                DBContentProvider.KEY_FAMILY_TEXT, DBContentProvider.KEY_GENUS_TEXT, DBContentProvider.KEY_SPECIES, 
                DBContentProvider.KEY_COMMON_NAME_GROUP, DBContentProvider.KEY_GROWTH_FORM_TEXT};
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), Uri.parse(DBContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_STRING + 
                "search"), dbPlantColumns, null, arguments, null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }// method: LoaderCallbacks.onCreateLoader(int, Bundle)

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor){
        adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }// method: LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor>, Cursor)

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader){
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }// method: LoaderCallbacks.onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor>)

    /* ListFragment response methods */
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id){
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

        plantSelectedListener.onPlantSelected(id /*Get id of plant at this position*/);
    }// method: ListFragment.onListItemClick(Listview, View, int, long)

    public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick){
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }// method: setActivateOnItemClick(boolean)

    private void setActivatedPosition(int position){
        if(position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION){
            getListView().setItemChecked(activatedPosition, false);
        } 
        else{
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        activatedPosition = position;
    }//method: setActiviatedPosition(int)

    /**
     * OnPlantSelectedListener is used by the fragment and the activity to 
     * make sure that the selection of a plant is dealt with correctly.
     */
    public interface OnPlantSelectedListener{
        public void onPlantSelected(long id);
    }// interface: OnPlantSelectedListener
}// class: ResultsFragment extends ListFragment
```

activity_results.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ResultsActivity"
    android:id="@+id/Results_Lin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- @android:id/list is the necessary id for the activity to find it. -->
    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/results_empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txt_no_results"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_results.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:name="edu.dordt.grassrootsplantid.ResultsFragment"
    android:id="@+id/Result_Fragment"/>
```

list_item_results.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Result_Item_Lin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_item_txt_lbl_common_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_common_name"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_item_txt_common_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/result_item_txt_lbl_common_name"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/result_item_txt_lbl_scientific_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/result_item_txt_lbl_common_name"
        android:text="@string/lbl_scientific_name"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_item_txt_genus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/result_item_txt_lbl_scientific_name"
        android:layout_below="@id/result_item_txt_lbl_common_name"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_item_txt_species"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/result_item_txt_genus"
        android:layout_below="@id/result_item_txt_lbl_common_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I probably misunderstand how to use fragments, but it was necessary in order to use the tutorial I was following for using Content Providers. I didn't put in the Content Provider here, but I'm pretty sure that's working (well...broken somewhere else, but I think I can handle that one). If someone wants to see it anyway, I can edit my question.

If it's at all relevant, the list items have their data and are clickable, but they appear greyed out as though they are unclickable. Perhaps that's a styling issue, but I would figure they would use the style shared by the rest of the app.

But to reiterate my problem, the listview is populating, but the adapter claims to be empty. I'm not sure how big of an issue it is/will be, but I would like either a way to get them to agree or an explanation of why they might not need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or an explanation of why they might not need to.

They seem not to agree because adapter is indeed empty at the time `isEmpty` is called. Android's `Loaders` do the work on a separate thread (asynchronously).

I suggest [setting empty view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29) instead of using toast.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, the api explanation for `setEmptyView()` didn't help much. I'm not finding how to implement that in the Activity or Fragment anywhere; I found a `setEmptyText()` for the Fragment, so I inserted that in the OnViewCreated method. I suppose that will work; otherwise it seems simple enough to put the toast in onLoadFinished as @dmon mentioned.

Either way, this doesn't explain why the text is grey. Is that a styling issue? And where would I fix that?

Comment: Then I think your question is not clear. The reason it's empty when you are showing the toast is because it's loading asynchronously, the data is not there yet. This has nothing to do with Fragments, per se. If you really want to show the toast (why?) you'd have to move it to onLoadFinished. And I have no clue why your views are grey.

Comment: I understood the reason the toast was showing up, so I did indeed move the toast declaration and that works (thanks, btw!). I was commenting on the issue I was having was with understanding what MaciejGorski wanted me to do with `setEmptyView`.

Comment: I also figured out the grey list items; I was using `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`, but I should have just been using `getActivity()`. So that turned out to be a different issue altogether.

Comment: @stspurg empty view can show the state, so while the data is loading it would show "loading..." and after load is finished, it would change to "Nobody is in your database. Fill it up!" or disappear if there is data. Just a better UX. Toasts can be overlooked easily and IMHO should be used only immediately after user interaction,.

Comment: @MaciejGórski The problem is that it is impossible for me to use `setEmptyView()` with the current layout (i.e. a listFragment). It is simply not available. So is `setEmptyText()` effectively the same thing? Otherwise how am I supposed to implement `setEmptyView()`.

Comment: Anywho, I'll mark this as the answer, since this thread did indeed answer the question. My issue was that I had forgotten about the multithreading inherent in the `Loader`, and I fixed it by putting my Toast message in `onLoadFinished()`. As far as how to indicate to the user that nothing was returned, I suppose that isn't related to this question.